# generate some statistics from my CVS

Tags: cvs

I want to generate some statistics from my CVS database! E.g how many files are currently versioned in CVS, rate of change of each file, %age of changes made to the each file for each commit.. etc . IF anyone is aware of such a modile, or a procedure to do the same, kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

The [StatCVS](http://statcvs.sourceforge.net) project generates statistics from a CVS Repository

You can also use the CVS history command to list all commits by
all users, import this into a relational database, and use SQL
statements to analyze the changes (this is a lot of manual work though). Use a command like:

```
    cvs history -c -a > cvs-history.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything specific, but CVS stores (almost) everything as *,v files in a directory tree.  Running `rlog` (part of `RCS`) on each of those *,v files should give you the information you need.  (You might want to use the `-z` option to control how timestamps are formatted.)

Collecting that information into something useful is a different matter.  (I'd write a Perl script myself.)